# sql find minimum value satisfying certain conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table and I want to get the row when the value of a particular columns is the minimum and the time is between 9:15 and 10:00 am.

this is my code

```
Select time, size, sym, price FROM test WHERE 
price = (Select MIN(price) from 
(select time, size, price from test where sym = 'PTX' And date = '2014-01-02' And time >=  '9:15'  And time <'10:00'  ) as test1
)
Group By sym, time, size, price;
```

I was hoping I would get something like:

```
     time     |  size  | sym  | price 
--------------+--------+------+-------
 9:53:32.486 |    100 | PTX  |  2.42
```

instead I'm getting

```
     time     |  size  | sym  | price 
--------------+--------+------+-------
 11:53:40.198 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 15:00:01.007 |    158 | AMD  |  2.42
 10:27:16.818 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 09:54:03.057 |     65 | GEVO |  2.42
 10:02:50.139 |     80 | SNTA |  2.42
 15:01:26.752 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 14:02:25.981 |   1100 | AMD  |  2.42
 14:35:20.165 |    882 | AMD  |  2.42
 13:22:25.701 |   1900 | AMD  |  2.42
 15:59:40.409 |    113 | SNTA |  2.42
 14:32:30.422 |  15900 | AMD  |  2.42
 09:32:39.217 |     50 | SNTA |  2.42
 10:58:37.311 |     10 | OREX |  2.42
 10:12:28.215 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 13:42:59.869 |    100 | OREX |  2.42
 11:13:12.193 |    100 | SNTA |  2.42
 09:40:25.264 |     98 | SNTA |  2.42
 11:02:04.777 |    200 | AMD  |  2.42
 12:02:37.364 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 09:51:47.947 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 15:52:23.795 |    100 | OREX |  2.42
 10:03:16.637 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 09:56:08.089 |    100 | AMD  |  2.42
 15:45:28.617 |   1200 | AMD  |  2.42
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `psql` is the command line client for Postgres so I re-tagged the question with `postgresql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method just uses `order by` and limits the results to a single row:

```
Select time, size, sym, price
from test 
where sym = 'PTX' And date = '2014-01-02' And time >= '9:15' And time < '10:00'
order by price
limit 1;
```

Note:  Some databases spell `limit` as `fetch first 1 row only`, use `top 1` in the `select`, or have similar methods for limiting the number of rows returned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the WHERE in the main query with the subquery. Currently you're finding min price for a condition but not applying the same condition to the main query. Try this:

```
Select time, size, sym, price FROM test WHERE 
price = (Select MIN(price) from 
(select time, size, price from test where sym = 'PTX' And date = '2014-01-02' And time >=  '9:15'  And time <'10:00'  ) as test1
) and sym = 'PTX' And date = '2014-01-02' And time >=  '9:15'  And time <'10:00'
Group By sym, time, size, price;
```